# VBA String Variable Contains Other Variable

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a string that I am trying to build with text and other variables.
Is there a way to build the string so that I can use other variables ?

I have a text file that my vba is reading to compose the body of an email.

The text file has this line:

```
email_body|"Final Reports will be distributed on or after \" & Me.cbo_Month.Column(0) & \" 10th.
```

I am calling the function

```
MessageBody = getAdmSetting("email_body")
```

which returns the string exactly:

```
Final Reports will be distributed on or after \" & Me.cbo_Month.Column(0) & \" 10th.
```

If I debug.print MessageBody, i get the string exactly. I am trying to get the value of Me.cbo_Month.Column(0) to print.

```
debug: Final Reports will be distributed on or after \" & Me.cbo_Month.Column(0) & \" 10th.
```

I would like it to print:
Final Reports will be distributed on or after January 10th.

Comment: Yes, you concatenate with `&`.

Comment: What is the issue? At glance, your string is structured correctly. Are you sure `Me.cbo_Month.Column(0)` returns a valid string to concatenate here?

Comment: maybe i didtn ask the correct question or post enough information.  I have a function that reads a text file for the body of an email.  I would like to be able to add variables into the text file.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have updated my original question.

Comment: [Eval Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/eval-function-8c4a1b10-85ba-40db-b0c8-5290da4d4166)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't easily evaluate random pieces of code in VBA like you can in some other languages.  You'd be better off using tokens which you replace.

In your text file:

```
email_body|Final Reports will be distributed on or after {month} 10th.
```

then you can

```
Debug.Print Replace(MessageBody, "{month}", Me.cbo_Month.Column(0))
```