# VBA String with embedded Variables

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a string that I am trying to build with text and other variables.
Is there a way to build the string so that I can use other variables ?

I have a text file that my vba is reading to compose the body of an email.

The text file has this line:

```
email_body|"Final Reports will be distributed on or after \" & Me.cbo_Month.Column(0) & \" 10th.
```

I am calling the function MessageBody = getAdmSetting("email_body") which returns the string exactly:Final Reports will be distributed on or after \" & Me.cbo_Month.Column(0) & \" 10th.

If I debug.print MessageBody, i get the string exactly. I am trying to get the value of Me.cbo_Month.Column(0) to print.

```
debug: Final Reports will be distributed on or after \" & Me.cbo_Month.Column(0) & \" 10th.
```

I would like it to print:
Final Reports will be distributed on or after January 10th.

Comment: Previously https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60400083/vba-string-variable-contains-other-variable (needs votes to re-open)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA String Variable Contains Other Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60400083/vba-string-variable-contains-other-variable)